# Is it safe to target styled components class names?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Im using styled components to build an app and need to reuse some components on another page but some of the style properties are slightly different.

Is it safe to do something like

```
div.Card-sc-17xtaz4-0 {
  box-shadow: unset;
  margin-top: unset;
  margin-bottom: unset;
}
```

or is the class name associated to the styled component likely to change at build time?

Comment: You can reuse SC with its API, don't try targeting them because they get a "random" id every build (should check it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not random, but it uses a hash library for the name and that will change if any prop of your component happen to change. Actually, it will change even if you add an extra space character inside your component CSS.

See the snippet below and try to uncomment the `color:red;` line and you'll see that the className changes. Comment it back **EXACTLY** as it was before and you'll get the old className back.

```js
const Container_DIV = window.styled.div`
  /* color: red; */
`;

function App() {
  const container_ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [classList,setClassList] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setClassList(container_ref.current.classList);
  },[]);
  
  return(
    <Container_DIV
      ref={container_ref}
    >
      I am Container_DIV, a styled-component!
      <div>
        <b>My className is: </b>{classList}
      </div>
    </Container_DIV>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**From:** https://medium.com/styled-components/how-styled-components-works-618a69970421

> Currently styled-components uses MurmurHash algorithm to create uniq identifier and then converts the hash number to alphabetic name.
>
> **Generating CSS class name:**
>
> Each component instance with uniq props has it’s own CSS class name which generated by means of the same MurmurHash algorithm but from the componentId and the evaluatedStyles string:

[image]